# Cordova iOS - plugin not loaded

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, plugins

I'm using Cordova (I tried many versions of this framework, current is 3.5) for iOS development and when I try to use a plugin, each time it's not working. I tried the following plugins: org.apache.cordova.dialogs and com.teamnemitoff.phonedialer.

The installation is complete, files are deployed in the right directories, links in build phase are present (files .m) but nothing works. I saw many discussions about this problem and tried many solutions but nothing solved my issue.

For the notification plugin, it doesn't solve the "undefined" response when I call the navigator.notification.alert method. I tried to add an alert in the js file (notification.js) but the message is not displayed so I assume the plugin is not properly loaded.

Could anyone help me?

Here is the content of the files config.xml and cordova_plugins.js :

---

cordova_plugins.js located (at platforms/ios/www/)

---

```
cordova.define('cordova/plugin_list', function(require, exports, module) {
module.exports = [enter code here
    {
        "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.dialogs/www/notification.js",
        "id": "org.apache.cordova.dialogs.notification",
        "merges": [
            "navigator.notification"
        ]
    }
];
module.exports.metadata = 
// TOP OF METADATA
{
    "org.apache.cordova.dialogs": "0.2.10"
}
// BOTTOM OF METADATA
});
```

`

---

And config.xml located at (MyTests/platforms/ios/MyTests/config.xml)

---

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.mydomain.mytests" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value=".25" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
    <preference name="GapBetweenPages" value="0" />
    <preference name="PageLength" value="0" />
    <preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page" />
    <preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated" />
    <feature name="LocalStorage">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage" />
    </feature>
    <name>MyTests</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVNotification" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

Comment: Did you run `cordova build` after installing the plugins?

Comment: Yes i ran it, and i saw in the config.xml the lines corresponding to the plugin declaration for the plugin load. But nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` in your view

Comment: navigator.notification always returns undefined, even after adding the plugin org.apache.cordova.dialogs. So i assume the plugin is not properly loaded but i have no errors that explains me something...

Comment: @Nakir, can you provide `config.xml` and `cordova_plugins.js` if you have (at platforms/ios/www/)

Comment: I gave the content of those two files above, thank you very much for your help Tien

Comment: @Nakir, nothing seems to be wrong there. Check was `cordova_plugins.js` been executed by adding some alerts

Comment: how do you add alerts in a file loaded in the staging folder ? because i tried but it seems not being interpreted...

Comment: after `cordova build`, add alerts than build project with Xcode. if alert didn't execute than it means that `cordova_plugins.js` wasn't included. try to add alert directly to cordova in `cordova.js`

Comment: I tried what you said and indeed cordova_plugins.js is not included. No alert shown... How is it possible ? Why should I specify the path to include it, isn't it included by the build command ? I don't understand

Comment: in theory you need to include only `cordova.js`. maybe the problem lays there? make sure that `cordova.js` included. try to alert it too :)